# app engine python gql query not running

Tags: python, google-app-engine

results_patientalerts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientAlerts WHERE patientinfo_ID=" + data_key + " AND alert_type!=3")

patientinfo_ID is db.IntegerProperty()

data_key is key which i got it from URL....

Comment: Tell us a little about your model please. What type is `patientinfo_ID`? Is it a `db.IntergerProperty`? Or is it a `db.ReferenceProperty`? What is `data_key`?

Comment: yeah! u r true. Its a db.IntergerProperty

Comment: Its running i got it:                                                 results_patientalerts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientAlerts WHERE patientinfo_ID=" + data_key + " AND alert_type!='3'")

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting query arguments inline is generally a bad idea. A much better way is to let the `db` library do this for you:

```
results_patientalerts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientAlerts WHERE patientinfo_ID = :1 AND alert_type != :2", data_key, 3)
```

By querying the database this way you avoid any query escaping, quoting and/or formatting issues, since it's done automatically.

As you didn't say what exactly doesn't work in this query I cannot say what the problem is with it, but it could be some sort of an issue related to the above.